# I want to have both string and null value in attribute of dynamodb that means for some rows data is there and for some rows there is no data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

By using Dynamo-db for an attribute I want data for some rows and for some rows it will be null that means we will leave as a blank, we will not enter anything into it.

Comment: Please give some more context about your question : Code you already tried, detailed expected results with examples, etc.

Comment: we used js for create, insert and display and to put values of string and blank value for an attribute in dynamodb.  Blank space means we should not enter an spacebar or anything we should leave like a null value.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not enforce data types on columns that are not part of the table definition (Partition and Sort keys of the base table, LSI and GSI). Therefore, you could set an attribute to NULL in one item (row) and set it to some other type (String, Number, Binary, String Set, Number Set, Binary Set, List, Map, Boolean) in another item.